# Use T-SQL custom function in C# code

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, t-sql, linq-to-sql

I have to define a custom function in my DB to calculate the "validity end date" of an entity.
This function will be used in a stored procedure, but I need the same logic in a web app.

I'm using Linq-to-sql to connect to my DB and to map tables to classes. So I'm wondering if there is a way to reuse the function defined in my DB. I'd like to extend my entity by a partial class. Do I have to rewrite the logic in my code?

**NOTE** I need to use **function** and not **stored procedure** in my C# code.

Comment: I'd advise you not to use LINQ to SQL. Microsoft discontinued it anyway. Use [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx), with which you can conveniently map stored procedures. That said, [here's an article by Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx) describing how to map and call a stored procedure with Linq to SQL.

Comment: Did you read the last sentence in my comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that is possible to call a function defined in SQL Server DB by Linq-to-Sql.

I just imported the function object in `dbml` context file. So I can invoke it this way:

```
context.fn_my_db_function(param1, param2, etc);
```

Simple!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Stored Procedure, then in your DBML designer can drag it to the Methods pane, this will try to automatically detect the return type and inputs and expose is via the context instances. You can use the Properties view in Visual Studio to map the return type to a table model, or a custom-defined one, or something, if needs be.

This is called just like a function in C#, for instance:

```
using (var context = new MyDataContext()) {
  var result = context.MyStoredProcedure(input);
}
```

Where `result` would be the mapped managed type, and `input` would be the required parameter argument(s).

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to rewrite the logic in my code?

Not if you want the database to execute it (psuedo):

```
public static YourReturnType Calculate(this TEntity foo)
{
    return database.ExecuteFunction("calculate", foo);
}
```

If you don't want a database roundtrip for every calculation then yes, you'll have to rewrite the logic in C#.

Comment: This can even be auto-generated, there's no need to create wrappers unless A) the return type can't be determined automatically and/or B) some added logic is needed.

Answer (score -1):

This is possible with Entity Framework. See this [link](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef/the-entity-framework-and-aspnet-getting-started-part-7) for your reference.

You can just map your Stored Procedure and create an access get Method.

But if you just want to execute your created procedure in your database. . See this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/diego/archive/2012/01/10/how-to-execute-stored-procedures-sqlquery-in-the-dbcontext-api.aspx).